# How Do I Restore Azure Functions Debug Functionality after localdb Removal?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 and had been developing Azure Functions no issue; I then had an issue where I my (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB wasn't working and ended up deleting and recreating. This worked fine in general; but has caused some issues with running Azure Functions locally.

Initial: I received messages about unable to start Azure Storage Emulator
Resolved: I manually created the AzureStorageEmulatorDb510 and ran the AzureStorageEmulator.exe init

That then let me start the Azure Functions

Current: However, now on start of Azure Functions I get a message "The listener for function was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.common: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.

I'm at a loss as to what to do next; if I run AzureStorageEmulator.exe status it says everything is fine; I've tried messing with the firewall (including turning it off); no luck ... I'm guessing it is related to the recreation of the localDb but just not sure how to get operational again

Comment: Give a try to delete and re-installing Azure storage emulator?

Comment: Yes, complete uninstall (and then to test ran up via visual studio and got message "unable to find storage emulator") and reinstall; back to the "listener for function unable to start" message

Comment: Did you set the connection string to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` in `local.settings.json`?

Comment: Yes, UseDevelopmentStorage=true set in local.settings.json

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to figure out the underlying issue; but I followed the following steps and was able to get things running again ... I'm guessing the key is around clean up of folders / files after removing Databases and the program (something with wrong permissions or similar); but of a brute force solution, but it worked

- Remove database from localdb
- Deleted any database files laying around from prior creation points (there was an old file in the user directory)
- Uninstall Storage Emulator
- Restart PC
- Delete any "cruft" leftover (Azure and Storage Emulator directories were still there)
- Restart PC
- Install Storage Emulator
- Run AzureStorageEmulator.exe start (this time it created the DB automatically; so no need to manually create that db)
- Started Azure Function

Success, no listener message issue; very odd ... again my only guess is something with permissions / files that were left around after the uninstall previously?

Answer (score 1):

Excluding the storage emulator and firewall, I think your problem is caused by DB.

Because I cannot reproduce your problem, I can only give two suggestions:

**1.** Delete and recreate your DB. According to your problem analysis, your problem is likely to be in the DB.

**2.** Directly use the storage account on the `Azure portal`